# Get max / min from array of strings (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Any ideas to calculate min / max from array of strings?

```
var arr = ['aab','aac','aad','abx'];
```

So far i have considered to use `.sort()` function depending max / min, and get first element of result.

But maybe you know better preforming solution?

EDIT: Array size is below 1k elements. By Min /max i meant alphabetic sort: first and last element.

Comment: what is `max` and `min` in this case?

Comment: What do you consider the 'min' and 'max' of a string in this case?

Comment: I don't understand. How do you want to calculate the max or min of a string?

Comment: Well if sorting would provide a meaningful answer then something like `.localeCompare()` could be used in a single pass.

Comment: The OP said he considered sort, so `max / min` one would assume is alpha sorted, first & last.

Comment: Iterate through your list and update min and max in each iteration step

Comment: "better preforming solution" if that's the size of your data, sorting performance should be the least of your concerns.

Comment: I provided an answer, but I feel this question should be improved. What do you mean by the `max/min`

Comment: Array size is below 1k elements. By Min /max i meant alphabetic sort first and last element.

Comment: the minimum is the element of an set for that no smaller elements exsist in the same  set. So some databases defien an Minimum for all orderable dataypes. Also python has minium which works with String too. Some also support Sum of strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Iterate through your list and update min and max in each iteration step

```js
function getMinMax(arr) {
  if (!arr) {
    return null;
  }
  var minV = arr[0];
  var maxV = arr[0];
  for (a of arr) {
    if (a < minV) minV = a;
    if (a > maxV) maxV = a;
  }
  return [minV, maxV];
}

console.log(getMinMax(['abc', 'aaa', 'abb']));
```

It should be much faster than `sort()` for large arrays. This algorithm is O(n) while `sort()` is at least O(n log(n)).

Comment: Note that this answer is case-sensitive: `['abigail', 'daniel', 'Denver']` will return 'Daniel' as the max string.
To prevent that, use String.localeCompare() with a third parameter: `if (a.localeCompare(minV, undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' }) < 0) minV = a;` and `if (a.localeCompare(maxV, undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' }) > 0) maxV = a;`

If you work in a language with accents, you might want to use `{ sensitivity: 'accent' }`

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use a sort,.

Another option is to use `Array.reduce` to maintain the `min` & `max` values.

Below is a working snippet showing this.

ps.  Your test data already had the min as the first element, and max as the last element, so I've altered the example array to have `zzz`, that of course would be `max`.

```js
var arr = ['aab','aac','zzz','aad','abx'];

var ret = arr.reduce((a, v) => {
  a.min = a.min === null ? v :
    v.localeCompare(a.min) < 0 ? v : a.min; 
  a.max = a.max === null ? v : 
    v.localeCompare(a.max) > 0 ? v : a.max;
  return a; }, 
{min: null, max: null});

console.log(ret);
```

Comment: sort will be o(nlog(n)), min/max is just o(n)

Comment: @Dee  There is no sort here, did  you mean that comment for the other answers?

Comment: yeah, i meant sorting shouldn't be an option

Answer (score 5):

To extend @Keith's answers.. if we want `min` or `max` only then `reduce` will be 1-liner.

```
const arr = ['aab', 'aac', 'aad', 'abx']
const min = arr.reduce((min, c) => c < min ? c : min) // 'aab'
const max = arr.reduce((max, c) => c > max ? c : max) // 'abx'
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few solutions to wrap your head around:

**Min/max based on length**

```
const output = arr.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
```

**Min/max as in alphabetical order**

```
const output = arr.sort();
```

**Extract the minimum and max**

```
const max = arr.sort(() => 1)[0];
```

Comment: While you're at it you should also show how to extract the minimum and maximum, since that's the question.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca. Noted

Comment: I see you modified the answer, but watch out, it's giving a TypeError for the argument to `sort`

Comment: Thank you for drawing my attention to it

Comment: Look, sorry if I'm being a pain in the neck, but that function you used to sort doesn't actually sort. Since OP said they meant lexicographic sorting you may as well just use `const min = arr.sort()[0];` to extract the min. And you're still missing the `max`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, you're actually not. I believe he can simply run `arr.sort().reverse()[0]` to get the max value

Comment: `const max = arr.sort(() => 1)[0];` this can't be right

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did (note that it mutates the original array):

```js
const myArray = ['beta', 'alpha', 'zeta', 'delta'];
const min = myArray.sort()[0];
const max = myArray.reverse()[0];
console.log({ min, max });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce in one pass but have to check what to return if the array is empty (currently returns undefined for both min and max)

```js
const arr = [
  'aab',
  'aac',
  'aad',
  'abx',
];

console.log(
  arr.reduce(
    ([min, max], item) => [
      min.localeCompare(item) > 0
        ? item
        : min,
      max.localeCompare(item) < 0
        ? item
        : max,
    ],
    [arr[0], arr[0]],
  ),
);
```